# Betta has a large black spot

Tags: health, aquarium, betta

My Betta has a large black spot on him and I don't know if I should be concerned about it or if it's just a natural birth mark I don't think it is but I can't find anything online about ITV so I need professional opinions on how to treat him if it's bad.

Comment: Without a picture it's going to be very difficult to answer this.

Comment: Remember that the advice you get here is not necessarily a 'professional opinion'. Most of us are enthusiastic amateurs or hobbyists.

Comment: please give more details,how long have you had this fish and have it been like it is the whole time.some information about your setup might be helpful like the size of your tank and the quality of the water(water test) and a picture can be very helpful.